# search last value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm fairly skilled in excel but I haven't come up with a really good solution for this problem yet. I have a matrix of prices. They are ordered in dates from left to right in columns. If the apartment isn't listed yet, the value is 0. If the apartment is sold, the value is also 0. The price/value of the apartment may differ over time so I can't not just search for MAX. I would like to have the latest value the unit had before it was sold and the price became 0. If I could walk from right to left in the row I would like to find the first value <>0.

| Unit | 1may | 2may | 3may | 4may | 5may | should return |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100 000 | 100 000 | 123 000 | 90 000 | 90 000 | 90 000 |
| B | 100 000 | 100 000 | 123 000 | 0 | 0 | 123 000 |
| C | 0 | 100 000 | 123 000 | 90 000 | 0 | 90 000 |
| D | 0 | 0 | 123 000 | 90 000 | 150 000 | 150 000 |

Comment: Something like `=LOOKUP(2,1/(B2:F2>0),B2:F2)` dragged down?

Comment: Thanks JvdV! I tried this kind of formula before but didn't got it to work. Now it seems to works for the cases I test. You saved me a lot of time now. Thanks a lot!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from **LOOKUP**, you can also use [XLOOKUP](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-xlookup-function) if you are using Excel 365. The logic of using **XLOOKUP** is similar to what you said:

> "If I could walk from right to left in the row I would like to find
> the first value <>0."

```
=XLOOKUP(1,--(B2:F2<>0),B2:F2,,0,-1)
```

[image: Solutions]

Comment: What is the difference between LOOKUP and XLOOKUP?

Comment: @NewDev I think Exceljet will give you a more comprehensive explanation of each of the function. In my opinion, **XLOOKUP** is more flexible when you want to do non-exact match and/or reverse lookups.

Answer (score 0):

[image: EXCEL-SOLUTION]

The formula on C7 returns the header with the date every time it finds the first 0 on each row. Doest it solve your problem?

```
=INDEX($A$1:$F$1;1000-(LARGE(INDEX((A2:F2=0) * (1000-(COLUMN(A2:F2))););1)))
```